# Не срабатывает условие в functions.php для отображения яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, яндекс-карты

У меня есть сайт на wordpress+woocommerce. На главную и еще на парочку страниц нужно поместить карту яндекса - допустим эту

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.76, 37.64],
      zoom: 10
    }),
    ltiRoute1 = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
      referencePoints: [
        "Москва, метро Речной вокзал",
        "Москва, метро Водный стадион",
      ]
    }, {
      // Радиус транзитных точек на маршруте.
      viaPointIconRadius: 10,
      // Радиус точечных маркеров в путевых точках.
      pinIconRadius: 10,
      wayPointStartIconColor: "#80C257",
      wayPointFinishIconColor: "#8470FF",
      wayPointIconColor: "black",
      routeStrokeWidth: 2,
      routeActiveStrokeWidth: 6,
      routeStrokeColor: "000088",
      routeActiveStrokeColor: "#FF4500",
      pinIconFillColor: "#BFEFFF",
      viaPointIconFillColor: "#FFD39B",
      transportMarkerIconColor: "#FFE4E1"
    }),


    multiRoute2 = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
      referencePoints: [
        "Москва, метро Войковская",
        "Москва, метро Сокол"
      ]
    }, {
      routeStrokeWidth: 2,
      routeActiveStrokeWidth: 4,
      routeStrokeColor: "000088",
      routeActiveStrokeColor: "#66CDAA"
    }),

    buttonRoute1 = new ymaps.control.Button({
      data: {
        content: "Первый маршрут"
      },
      options: {
        maxWidth: 300
      }
    }),

    buttonRoute2 = new ymaps.control.Button({
      data: {
        content: "Второй маршрут"
      },
      options: {
        maxWidth: 300
      }
    });


  myMap.controls.add(buttonRoute2);
  myMap.controls.add(buttonRoute1);


  myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute1);
  myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute2);



  buttonRoute1.events.add('select', function() {
    if (buttonRoute2.isSelected()) {
      buttonRoute2.deselect();
    }
    myMap.setBounds(multiRoute1.getBounds());
  });


  buttonRoute2.events.add('select', function() {
    if (buttonRoute1.isSelected()) {
      buttonRoute1.deselect();
    }
    myMap.setBounds(multiRoute2.getBounds());
  });


  multiRoute.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function() {
    var wayPoints = multiRoute1.getWayPoints();
    wayPoints.get(0).properties.set('name', 'текст'); //Для метро Речной Вокзал
  });


}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard,package.geoObjects&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
```

[фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/9aj8j/)

Как так прописать условие, чтобы ошибок карты не вываливалось на других страницах?

Делаю проверку в файле `functions.php`:

```
if (is_home() || is_page(1825)) {
    function yandex_api() {
        wp_enqueue_script('yandexmap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ya-map.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('yandexapi', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/yandex-maps.js');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yandex_api');
}
```

но не работает.. если убрать условие - карта появляется. Что тут не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверка должна была проводиться внутри функции:

```
function yandex_api(){
if( is_home() || is_page( 1825 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'yandexmap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ya-map.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'yandexapi', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/yandex-maps.js' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yandex_api' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Подгружайте свой код `JS` только на нужных страницах. Проверяйте условия на `PHP` и если подходит, то выводим скрипт инициализации карты.

### UPD

Весь ваш код `JS` поместите в условный оператор `if`

```
...
<?php if(is_home()): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // ваш js код
    </script>
    <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard,package.geoObjects&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
...
```

Comment: "Подгружайте свой код JS только на нужных страницах." @korytoff как??  в этом же и сама суть вопроса!

Comment: Это конечно будет работать, но это - костылестроение.

Comment: @tutankhamun согласен

Comment: @korytoff я добавил условие по вашему совету в файл functions.php но оно там не работает...

Comment: @Вася, на самом деле мой совет это действительно костыль, лучше воспользуйтесь новым шаблоном для нужных вам страниц

Comment: @korytoff каким шаблоном? на самом деле вариант с подключением через конфигурационный файл считаю самым оптимальным! вопрос только почему условие не читается..?

Comment: @Вася не знаю, могу только посоветовать дебажить и смотреть мануал – https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home#Usage

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь [шорткодами](https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:Shortcode_API). Или сами напишите свой плагин или воспользуйтесь имеющимся [плагином Яндекс.Карт](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oi-yamaps/)

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо показывать карту вне блока контента, можно сделать специальный шаблон страницы и показывать нужные страницы с этим шаблоном. Также если нужно показывать буквально на двух-трех страницах, можно сделать шаблоны, которые будут привязаны к идентификаторам страниц.

Как это сделать можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) (по-английски) или в [статье](http://wp-kama.ru/id_5177/3-sposoba-sozdat-shablon-stranitsyi.html) (по-русски)